# How to map HTML to Python dictionary recursively?

Tags: python, html

I've seen a few articles specifically on HTML tables, but I want to know how I can map an entire HTML file to a Python dictionary (to later be turned into JSON). The HTML I'm mapping is mostly text pages from a Confluence API call (with maybe a few images).

An Example input:

```html
<h1>This is a header</h1>
<p>Here is a paragraph with <b>some bold text!</b>Some more words here.</p>
<div>
    <h2>Here is a nested header</h2>
</div>
```

Example Output:

```py
{
    "h1": "This is a header",
    "p":{
        "text_content0": "Here is a paragraph with "
        "b": "some bold text!",
        "text_content1": "Some more words here."
    },
    "div":{
        "h2": "Here is a nested header"
    }
}
```

I know that this will have to be recursive. I've been looking into the HTML Parser that is a part of Python and I've been trying to think of a way to work recursive functionality into the example that they provide:

```py
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print("Encountered a start tag:", tag)

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        print("Encountered an end tag :", tag)

    def handle_data(self, data):
        print("Encountered some data  :", data)

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed('<html><head><title>Test</title></head>'
            '<body><h1>Parse me!</h1></body></html>')
```

Would anyone know a way of modifying this example (or something from scratch) in order to create a nested dictionary that fully represents the HTML file?

Comment: I'm assuming you're not particularly attached to the format of your example output. It contains a dictionary with the key `text_content` appearing more than once.

Comment: No I'm not too attached to it hehe. It's more of the principal of having the tags and nesting represented in a dictionary format.

Comment: what if you just use elementtree (in Python standard library) to read in the html? it parses it all to a nested tree of xml elements. then you can easily output that as json. Also, there seems to be a ready made tool for this: https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict

Comment: Thanks @antont I'll check out that tool!